# Configure Gmail SMTP with Wordpress

Tags: gmail, smtp, wordpress

I've been trying to configure the GMAIL SMTP plugin on Wordpress for a client and I'm stumped as to why it's not working. The configuration and OAuth works fine, but when I send a test email I get this error:

Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

From everything I've read it seems to not be an issue with the plugin, but more likely with Google. This is a Google apps for business account. The domain name is from GoDaddy and the Wordpress site is on shared hosting from NameCheap.

I've tried changing the ports in the SMTP from 587 to 465 and 25, but that didn't work. I also have the Google account set to allow less secure apps. I'm not the admin on the Google account, so I can't email them directly.

Also FYI this is Wordpress 4.5.3 and Gmail SMTP plugin 1.0.6

I don't know where to go from here. Any help would be approeciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help someone else who reads this, but the answer was just that I needed to contact Namecheap, my shared host, to open up port 587. Once they did that the gmail SMTP still didn't work, but the WP-SMTP plugin worked!